Specify the current (interim or stable) release in `uvtool` filter arguments
I'm trying to write a script that automatically creates a VM using the daily Ubuntu cloud image of the latest interim release. Currently, that's oracular (Ubuntu 24.10), but this label will change every 6 months.
How can I replace oracular in the uvt-simplestreams-libvirt sync command below to request the daily image for "whatever the current release is"?
uvt-simplestreams-libvirt sync release=oracular label=daily arch=amd64

